# How to use the current interface as a parameter to an property that receives a generic type of the current interface? C# OOP

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

First of all, I know that the question title is a little messy, but I was unable to write a better one.

Here is my case:

```
    public interface ITypeX
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IItemX<TTypeX>
        where TTypeX: class, ITypeX
    {
        public ITypeX TypeX { get; set; }
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ICommentX<IItemX<TTypeX>>> Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICommentX<TItem>
        where TItem: class, IItemX<ITypeX>
    {
        public TItem ItemX { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

In the `Comments` property, I get the following error

> CS0311 - The `IItemX<TTypeX>` type cannot be used as TItem type parameter in the `ICommentX<TItem>` generic type or method. There is no implicit reference conversion from `IItemX<TTypeX>` to `IItemX<ITypeX>`.

I can fix the error just changing the property to

```
public IEnumerable<ICommentX<IItemX<ITypeX>>> Comments { get; set; }
```

It works, but I lose the restriction that the Comment's `ItemX` must be the same `TypeX` in question.

What I really wished it could be possible is something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ICommentX<this>> Comments { get; set; }
```

considering that this is a property of the interface I will pass as a parameter.

Hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: `this` isn't an interface. It's a keyword that refers to the current object. What you ask seems to be about interface covariance and contravariance, not `this`

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Seems like you need to add another generic type as in `IComment<TItem, TTypeX> where TItem : class, IItemX<TTypeX> where TTypeX : class, ITypeX`